# How to add a popup menu in i-Phone on a button click?

Tags: ios, popupwindow

i am a beginner to iOS development.

I was trying to display a pop-up menu on click of a button. And i need to display some other action titles like update, delete,cancel on that pop-up menu. Could anyone please me to solve this?

Comment: Have you looked at UIActionSheet?

Comment: i was looking for a controller just ike UIPopoverController in i pad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look into UIActionSheet and/or UIPopover.

UIActionSheet:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html

UIPopover:
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Note: UIPopovers are currently only for iPad but there are open source projects out there that recreate it for iPhone as well: 
https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover/